# Stacking Multindex Data Frame with Multindex Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to stack a data frame with multiple levels for its row values, and a single level for its column values. The original dataframe looks like this (where Time is the name for the single level in df.columns):

```
Time                                      +1hr   +2hr   +3hr   ... 
Cytokine Antibody Peptide Concentration
IFNg     CD28     N4     1uM              0.1    0.2.   0.3.   
TNFa.    CD28.    N4.    1uM              0.2    0.4.   0.6.   
...
```

And I'm trying to stack the dataframe to get an output like this:

```
Cytokine                             IFNg  TNFa  ...
Antibody Peptide Concentration Time
CD28     N4.     1uM           +1hr  0.1.  0.2
CD28     N4.     1uM           +2hr  0.2.  0.4
CD28     N4.     1uM           +3hr  0.3.  0.6
...
```

Unfortunately, df.stack() returns this:

```
Time                                          +1hr  +2hr  +3hr ...
Cytokine Antibody Peptide Concentration Time
IFNg     CD28     N4.     1uM           +1hr  0.1.  na    na
         CD28     N4.     1uM           +2hr  na    0.2.  na
         CD28     N4.     1uM           +3hr  na    na    0.3
TNFa     CD28     N4.     1uM           +1hr  0.2.  na    na
         CD28     N4.     1uM           +2hr  na    0.4.  na
         CD28     N4.     1uM           +3hr  na    na    0.6
...
```

Despite the pandas documentation saying that stacking data frames with single level columns will output a series, I end up getting a large data frame when I attempt to stack (even though df.columns.nlevels returns 1). When I remove the name of the column levels (Time), it works fine, but I'd like to keep that in. Is there anything I can do to get the stacking working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself, but thought I might as well document the solution. If the name of the single level for the column values is assigned directly (e.g. df.columns.name = 'Time'), stacking works as expected. Single level multindices don't work with df.stack().